# Generic NotNullWhen for Func argument

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a function like this:

```
public class X {
public T GetOrNew<T, TKey>(TKey? key, Func<TKey?, T> factory){

// omitted code

var instance = factory(key);

// omitted code

return instance

}

}
```

Now the problem is that the following usage generates nullable warnings:

```
// Here key is never allowed to be null.
public Person GetPerson(StreetIndex key){

_ = key ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: nameof(key));

var x = new X();

// so here key is never null, so index is never null
x.GetOrNew(key, index => index.GetRandomPerson()); // warning on index.GetRandomPerson because it could be null according to the signature.

// this call should also work and not give any nullable warnings.
x.GetOrNew<StreetIndex, Person>(null, _ => new PersonFactory.Birth());

}
```

Of course looking at the code it becomes clear that the `key` passed to the factory is only `null` when the parameter to `GetOrNew` is `null`.

Is there any attribute (or pattern) to indicate this?

For "normal" functions such as `Person? Mogrify(StreetIndex? key)` I can use `[return: NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(key))`.

Note that I do need to support `null` as valid parameter to `GetOrNew`.

Comment: `x.GetOrNew(null, _ => new PersonFactory.Birth());` cannot work under any circumstances. There is no way for the compiler to infer the type of `TKey`. You'll need to write `x.GetOrNull<Person, StreetIndex>(null, _ => new PersonFactory().Birth())`,  or pass in a typed null with e.g. `x.GetOrNull((StreetIndex)null, ...)` or `x.GetOrNull(default(StreetIndex), ...)`

Comment: @canton7 You are right in that regard. Now that we have cleared that, can you suggest an appropriate annotation for suppressing the nullable warnings?

Comment: My answer shows you the correct annotation. You rejected it because of this above unrelated issue: perhaps you could re-read it with this in mind?

Comment: (Note that using attributes is a non-starter here - you can't apply an attribute to a generic type argument, so there's no way to annotate the `TKey` type argument to `Func<TKey, T>`. This causes pain in particular with `Task<T>`, but as yet there's no language solution)

Comment: q: should `new PersonFactory.Birth()` be `new PersonFactory().Birth()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current signature is saying "Even when `TKey` is a non-nullable type, `key` and that `factory` parameter can be null".

Instead, you can declare your method:

```
public T GetOrNew<T, TKey>(TKey key, Func<TKey, T> factory)
```

This says "When `TKey` is a nullable type, then `key` and that `factory` parameter can be null; otherwise if `TKey` is a non-nullable type, then `key` and that `factory` parameter cannot be null".

This means that this is permitted:

```
AnotherClass? key = null;
GetOrNew(key, theKey => new AnotherClass());
```

And this doesn't generate nullable warnings:

```
AnotherClass key = new AnotherClass();
GetOrNew(key, theKey => theKey.DoIt());
```

[See here on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK7wCYgNQB8ACATAIwCwAUBQMQyoA2dEwdApgAQsxOsUUBuEZGwQsAzgjYBeNjBYB3NgBUxCABQBKANy9yAQRgB7BAAsWyAMKNRogPxsA1sSkz6dbeRHiAdAHEWCAHlkADl5VUc4NgB9KQA+GXk2fSNTCytRDS0dZJMzSwhrB0JnWQUc1PzrDXdPBF9/INC5cMJI3IBpFgBPOOFTTq6vABEDAEk1dSzKcnwAZjYiJRUKAG8KNg2NuaU2P0CQ+QAeRUjFAdjVM+6Hbsj8AFZjgdP4gDMIAGMEA2Qu9XXNmw1uRAaD8AB2NgYFjvegIACE7lBAF8KKjpttFuU8ulVgDNttsWkCqI2CNxhpeiYoKJNJs0UA==).

---

Note that:

```
GetOrNull(null, _ => ...);
```

Can never work, regardless of nullability. The compiler needs to infer a type for `TKey`, and the only information you've given is that it can be `null`, which isn't enough information for it to go on.

You'll either need to specify `TKey` explicitly:

```
GetOrNull<StreetIndex?, Person>(null, _ => ...);
```

Or use a typed null:

```
GetOrNull((StreetIndex?)null, _ => ...)
GetOrNull(default(StreetIndex?), _ => ...)
```

Or indeed, give the type information in the `factory` parameter:

```
GetOrNull(null, (StreetIndex? _) => ...)
```

Comment: I thought of that but then I cannot do `GetOrNew(null, _ => new Something())`. Which the question states must be supported.

Comment: @RedX There's no scenario in which you can do that -- the code in your question fails to compile there as well. [Link](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK7wCYgNQB8ACATAIwCwAUBTAKYDuABACrUDOCAFAJQB0A4tQgDyyAHJ12MVABspcegH16AXgB89AEQJWCdZwDcFCvgDM9Ik20UA3hXp27JpvX5DRdADyM5jANLUAnirsvgEA/PQA1gFy+ACsnn7+od5qAGYQAMYIAPbI/py29vQ25EVl+ADs9BjU6dIIBqVFAL4UzUA==). That's related to the fact that the compiler has no way to figure out what type `TKey` has, rather than anything to do with nullable warnings.

Comment: @RedX However, with my code you can write e.g. `string? key = null; GetOrNew(key, _ => "")` -- this infers `TKey` as being a nullable `string?` type, and so both `key` and the input param to `factory` can be null. [Link](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK7wCYgNQB8ACATAIwCwAUBQMQyoA2dEwdApgAQsxOsUX7EAGAPxsAzmwC8bWgwDcFGCwDubACotRCABQBKAHQBxFggDyyAHLKtouGwD6kgHxsARAg0IXO+ZXL4AzGxEah4UAN4UbFFRAWpsRqYWygA8qraqANIsAJ6OWpk5IgDWObb4AKypWdlC6c4AZhAAxggA9sjZOpHRbBHkPQP4AOxsGCyN9Ag+AwC+FDNAA=)

Comment: @RedX I've edited my answer to clarify what I think is confusing you. Please take a look.

Comment: When I try your suggestion `GetOrNew<T, TKey>(Tkey, Func<TKey, T>)` I get a warning when trying to use it with `GetOrNew<SomeType, SomeKeyType>(null, _ => MakeNew())` on passing null. Because in the signature `Tkey` is not nullable.

Comment: @RedX Call `GetOrNew<SomeType, SomeKeyType?>(null, _ => MakeNew())` if you want `TKey` to be nullable

Comment: So it seems that might misunderstanding of the situation. Your solution does work. It's an internal function that does not like the annotation. I'll need to figure that out.

Comment: For some reason I thought that TKey could not be nullable so I had to add the quesiton mark: TKey?. But it seems that it was a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: Yeah, as I said at the start of my answer, `TKey? key` means "Even if `TKey` isn't a nullable type, `key` is allowed to be null".

Answer (score 0):

So what happens if `theKey` is null? It will throw an exception. What would you like to happen? e.g. you could return a new object

```cs
x.GetOrNew(key, theKey => theKey?.DoIt() ?? new();
```

edit: it seems you want to give your user flexibility on how to call `GetOrNew`. You could do the null checking in the implementation of that method, e.g.

```cs
var instance = key is not null ? factory(key) : new();
```

Note that `GetOrNew(null, _ => new Whatever())` will likely not work, as the type of `TKey` cannot be determined from the first argument. (At best it will be `object?`).

You could add an overload to support that:

```cs
    public class X
    {
#nullable enable
        public T GetOrNew<T, TKey>(TKey? key, Func<TKey?, T> factory)
            where T : class, new()
        {
            // omitted code
            var instance = key is not null ? factory(key) : new();
            // omitted code
            return instance;
        }

        public T GetOrNew<T>(object? key, Func<object?, T> factory)
            where T : class, new() =>
            GetOrNew<T, object?>(key, factory);
#nullable restore
    }
```

Comment: You're right that"s unclear from the question. Yes returning a default constructed is an option. Or call some other method that can handle a nullable key. `GetOrNew(null, key => someOtherFactoryIhave.ConstructFrom(key))` or even `GetOrNew(null, _ => new Whatever())`. The user should not be constrained.